# Use a Map with AssetImage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a scenario where I would like to load an image based on the text that is chosen to be displayed on the app.

For example, I have a map that looks like this:

```
final _activity = const [
    {'Activity': 'Rock Climbing','Image':'assets/images/rockclimbing.jpg'},
    {'Activity': 'Running','Image':'assets/images/running.jpg'},
];
```

If I want to display the text related to an Activity in a Text Widget I can do the following:

```
Text(
  activity[activityNumber]['Activity'],
),
```

However, I would also like to display the corresponding image, here is what I have tried that does not work:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
  image: const DecorationImage(
    image:AssetImage (activity[activityNumber]['Image']),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

I have also tried wrapping this in quotes, curly braces etc but I cannot make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing should work:

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(_activity[activityNumber]['Image']),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Have you considered using Image.asset? Something like: `Image.asset(_activity[activityNumber]['Image'])`

Comment: `Image.asset(_activity[activityNumber]['Image'])` does work, but am I able to use that with BoxDecoration?

Comment: No, BoxDecoration image expects a DecorationImage. What kind of error do you get with your code?